# Exception in thread-ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

The following code compiles, but I get an `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException` error when I try to run it. I'm learning Java by reading the *Thinking in Java*-book, and I pretty much copied the code from the solutions guide. Help is very much appreciated.

```
public class MainLine
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(args[0]);
    System.out.println(args[1]);
    System.out.println(args[2]);
}
```

Comment: Are u passing anything from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ensure you pass the arg in command line.

To prevent exception, the better way is to check the length first.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)  {
        System.out.println(args[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The args[] array is determined by the arguments you send to the program when you run it. The problem is you are not given the program at least 3 arguments.

To do this more safely use the `args.length` to get the size of the array and then don't access any cell at `args.length` or greater.